# React input element's onChange using setState() doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, events, onchange

I want to make an app so that when text is typed in input element this will reflect that change in output. So far the updating doesn't work :(

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: [
      { username: 'Kai' },
      { username: 'Orange' }
    ]
  }

  inputChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        user: [
          { username: e.target.value },
          { username: e.target.value }
        ]
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserInput onChange={this.inputChangeHandler} />
        <UserOutput username={this.state.user[0].username} />
        <UserOutput username={this.state.user[1].username} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Change in text typed in input element should be reflected as username rendered in UserOutput. This doesn't work.

Here are codes for other components...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserInput extends Component
{
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserInput;
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserOutput extends Component
{
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>First paragraph and my name is {this.props.username}</p>
                <p>Second paragraph </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserOutput;
```

Comment: If you log `this.state.user` in your render, can you see the user array getting udpated as you type? Also, how are you rendering the username in `UserOutput`?

Comment: inside UserOutput: <div>
    <p>First paragraph and my name is {this.props.username}</p>
    <p>Second paragraph </p>
   </div>

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've provided that would cause an error. Add the code for your `UserInput` and `UserOutput` components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there's your problem. You're not assigning the change handler to the input element in your `UserInput` component. It should be:

```
<input onChange={this.props.onChange} />
```